# Why calling a new thread will not work in AsyncTask's doInbackground()?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, dalvik

While this will work:

```
new Thread(new Classimplementingrunnable(stuff, dostuff()).start();
```

This will not:

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        Log.i("tag", "I am inside thread");
        dostuff();
    }
};
```

No error occurs, it will just ignore it and it wont start a seperate thread, so "I am inside thread" will not show.

Comment: Call ``start()`` in latter case too. But it would be better, I guess, to always pass Thread a Runnable instead of overloading Thread.run().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `start()` method on your Thread inorder to make it run.

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Log.i("tag", "I am inside thread");
        dostuff();
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: you are absolutely right and I am ashamed I couldn't see it, too tired I guess, I was thinking more deeply into this problem than I should.